# add data before sending in android dynamic listview

Tags: android, json, listview, dynamic, android-listview

I have dynamic listview activity it transfer the item to another activity that have edit text(name,phone,table) and another dynamic listview under that.

the each item have edit text it should send with each item.

```
public class OrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<Item> orderItems;
private DatabaseHelper helper;

public OrderAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    ctx = context;
    helper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    orderItems = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return orderItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return orderItems.get(position).getItemID();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


public class ViewHolder {

    TextView name, desc, price, total;
    EditText etQty;
    Button btnDelete, btnAdd, btnMinus;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.order_preview_row, parent,
                false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.c_table);
        holder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_item_name);
        holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvOpPrice);
        holder.etQty = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etQty);

        holder.btnAdd = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnIncreaseQty);

        holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                float total_qty = (Float.parseFloat(holder.etQty.getText()
                        .toString()) + 1);

                Item item = (Item) holder.etQty.getTag();
                item.setNoItems(String.valueOf(total_qty));

                holder.etQty.setText(String.valueOf(total_qty));

                holder.total.setText(" = "
                        + (Float.parseFloat(orderItems.get(position)
                                .getItemPrice()) * Float
                                .parseFloat(holder.etQty.getText().toString())));
            }
        });

        holder.btnMinus = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnDecreaseQty);

        holder.btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Float total_qty = (Float.parseFloat(holder.etQty.getText()
                        .toString()) - 1);

                if (total_qty != 0) {

                    Item item = (Item) holder.etQty.getTag();
                    item.setNoItems(String.valueOf(total_qty));

                    holder.etQty.setText(String.valueOf(total_qty));

                    holder.total.setText(" = "
                            + (Float.parseFloat(orderItems.get(position)
                                    .getItemPrice()) * Float
                                    .parseFloat(holder.etQty.getText()
                                            .toString())));

                }
            }
        });

        holder.btnDelete = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteItem);

        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                helper.deleteItem(orderItems.get(position).getItemID());
                orderItems.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.total = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
        holder.etQty.setTag(orderItems.get(position));
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.etQty.setTag(orderItems.get(position));
    }

    holder.name.setText(orderItems.get(position).getItemName());
    holder.desc.setText(orderItems.get(position).getItemDescription());
    holder.price.setText(orderItems.get(position).getItemPrice() + " x ");

    holder.etQty.setText(orderItems.get(position).getNItems());

    holder.total
            .setText(" = "
                    + (Float.parseFloat(orderItems.get(position)
                            .getItemPrice()) * Float
                            .parseFloat(holder.etQty.getText().toString())));

    return convertView;
}

}
```

my problem is how to call the data from edit text to add it with the each item

for example the item name is :"Cheese Pizza" i want it "2 Cheese Pizza"

```
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            item_ids = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < orderItems.size(); i++) {
                item_ids.append(orderItems.get(i).getItemID()).append(",");
            }

            if (item_ids.length() == 0)
                return false;
            else
                item_ids.deleteCharAt(item_ids.length() - 1);

            Log.d("OrderPreview", item_ids.toString());

            item_names = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < orderItems.size(); i++) {
                item_names.append(orderItems.get(i).getItemName()).append(",");
            }

            if (item_names.length() == 0)
                return false;
            else
                item_names.deleteCharAt(item_names.length() - 1);

            Log.d("OrderPreview", item_names.toString());



            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Utils.WS_ADD_ORDER);

            List<NameValuePair> mParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", etName.getText()
                    .toString()));
            mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", etPhone.getText()
                    .toString()));
            mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("table", etTable.getText()
                    .toString()));
            mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("order_status", "Processing"));
            mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", item_ids.toString()));
            mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("items", item_names.toString()));
```

Comment: What's the issue exactly?

Comment: i want to call the variable from etQty edit text by to print it with item_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a method in your adapter to add new items in existing list of items.
and call that method in your async task when you are getting new dataset from your services/APIs.. Do not forget to put notifyDataSetChanged() in that method inside adapter.

Comment: thanks sir i try to do that but maybe i wrote it by wrong way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422353/add-data-to-custom-listview-scrolling-list/30422393#30422393  reffer this... this also same kind of problem.